# How can I remove .NET in my Angular.js project?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I use angular.js to develop my SPA website.

Now my website depended on ASP.NET MVC.
There is only one .cshtml file(homepage), and others are all .html.

When I open my site, the Index action of HomeController will return the homepage view, and the **Bundle** in .NET will minify all js and css files in homepage. So when I switch .html pages via angular.js, I have no need to reload js or css because all .html are switch via ng-view and the homepage.cshtml likes a master page.

Now I want to remove .NET and become pure front project, then I can depoly my site on other web server.
I can replace ASP.NET MVC with calling APIs directly.

**Q**:
1.Is there any front soluctions replace **Bundle**(minify js and css files)?
2.If I remove all .NET code and all pages become .html, how can I load my homepage without input url like *http://www.XXXXXX.com/homepage.html*? or do all web servers will load index.html in root path automatically?

Answer (score 1):

GruntJS maybe the solution. But is a command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a frontend solution (if you mean browser based). You can using command line tools like [yuicompressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) or ajaxminifier to create scripts and automate these tasks. See these blog posts

http://rickardnilsson.net/post/2011/03/26/Combining-and-minifying-JavaScript-and-CSS-files-with-Ajax-Minifier.aspx

http://encosia.com/automatically-minify-and-combine-javascript-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Good decision to separate the two technologies.  I would start with [ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ng-boilerplate).  The instructions are very well written and should get you started.

Your workflow would look something like this:

1. Open IDE
2. Run "cmd"
3. C:>cd path/to/angular/src
4. C:>grunt watch
5. Design your life away, grunt will watch file system and rebuild on changes. I just use the IDE for autocomplete and syntax checking.

PS: If you are doing authentication this module will help you:
https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth

Good luck